# How to use NSTimer with creating but not running?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have one problem: when i create `NSTimer` with:

```
NSTimer *some_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(gamePlay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I have a problem, my timer is immediately run.

How i need to write code to create timer, but run and start when it need, with some method???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it using `+alloc/-initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`, with a fire date far in the future, and send it a `-setFireDate:` message when you want it to start.

What I'm not understanding about your question is why you want to create  the timer before you need it do to anything?

Comment: The answer is obviously. I need to create timer in viewDidLoad with example 10 sec. time interval, when timer call method, method change the interval of timer. Also i have method what paused the game, question how i can paused timer and continue him after?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move this code to the event that you would fire on your "run and start when it need".

If you want to start after a defined period, then the solution of NSResponder would suffice your needs.